# Return an RDD from takeOrdered, instead of a list

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

I'm using pyspark to do some data cleaning. A very common operation is to take a small-ish subset of a file and export it for inspection:

```
(self.spark_context.textFile(old_filepath+filename)
    .takeOrdered(100) 
    .saveAsTextFile(new_filepath+filename))
```

My problem is that takeOrdered is returning a list instead of an RDD, so saveAsTextFile doesn't work.

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'saveAsTextFile'
```

Of course, I could implement my own file writer. Or I could convert the list back into an RDD with parallelize. But I'm trying to be a spark purist here.

Isn't there any way to return an RDD from takeOrdered or an equivalent function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`takeOrdered()` is an [action and not a transformation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-operations) so you can't have it return an RDD.
If ordering isn't necessary, the simplest alternative would be `sample()`.
If you do want ordering, you can try some combination of `filter()` and `sortByKey()` to reduce the number of elements and sort them. Or, as you suggested, re-parallelize the result of `takeOrdered()`