# How save list to file in spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341897/return-an-rdd-from-takeordered-instead-of-a-list), but I still need random.

I have datasets, like the follow:

```
123456789
23458ef12
ef12345ea
111223345
```

I want to get some ranom lines from it, so I write the follow pyspark code:

```
rdd = spark_context.textFile('a.tx').takeSample(False, 3)
rdd.saveAsTextFile('b.tx')
```

So takeSample returns on list, it will have one error:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'saveAsTextFile'
```

Comment: `takeSample()` returns array. you need parallelize it and save it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`takeSample()` returns array. you need parallelize it and save it.

```
rdd = spark_context.textFile('a.tx')
spark_context.parallelize(rdd.takeSample(False, 3)).saveAsTextFile('b.tx')
```

But the best way is to use [`sample()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#sample(boolean,%20double,%20long))(Here, I am taking 30%) which will return **RDD**

```
rdd.sample(False, 0.3).saveAsTextFile('b.tx')
```

Comment: Note that the second argument of `sample` is a fraction value that should be between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to begin from a pure python list ; such as on the result of calling `.collect()` on a pyspark dataframe, I have the following function

```
def write_lists_to_hdfs_textfile(ss, python_list, hdfs_filename):
    '''
    :param ss : SparkSession Object
    :param python_list: simple list in python. Can be a result of .collect() on pyspark dataframe.
    :param hdfs_filename : the path of hdfs filename to write
    :return: None
    '''

    # First need to convert the list to parallel RDD
    rdd_list = ss.sparkContext.parallelize(python_list)

    # Use the map function to write one element per line and write all elements to a single file (coalesce)
    rdd_list.coalesce(1).map(lambda row: str(row)).saveAsTextFile(hdfs_filename)

    return None
```

Eg:

`write_lists_to_hdfs_textfile(ss,[5,4,1,18],"/test_file.txt")`